# Resizing the text box with window in win32 api c

Tags: c++, api, winapi

i am very new to win32 API coding.
Currently i am facing a problem :

1. I've created a mdi child window and have inserted a text box into it.The problem stands when I click the maximize button of the mdi child window,the window expands but the text box dimension remains constant as mentioned in the coding.My question is how to re-size the text box along with the window.

I am using turboc++ 4.5 editor.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, problem solved:

```
LRESULT  CALLBACK _export ChildProc( HWND hChild, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM      lParam )
```

{

```
HWND    Edit1;
HINSTANCE hInstance1;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
int nWidth,nHeight;
 switch (iMessage)
 {

         case WM_CREATE :


         case WM_SIZE:  ''''''mentioned  by Jerry Coffin
                                            hInstance1 = GetWindowWord(hChild,GWW_HINSTANCE);
                                        Edit1 = CreateWindow("EDIT","",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_MULTILINE|ES_READONLY| WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL| WS_BORDER,0,0,1000,500,hChild,100,hInstance1,NULL);
                                        nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);  /* width  */
                                        nHeight = HIWORD(lParam); /* height */

                                        MoveWindow (Edit1,0,0,nWidth,nHeight,1);
                                            ShowWindow(Edit1,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                                        break;
         default :
                return DefWindowProc( hChild, iMessage, wParam, lParam );
 }
 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to handle the `WM_SIZE` message in the MDI child window. When you receive it, you'll want to use `MoveWindow` on the text box to resize it to fill the MDI child window.

As an aside: Turbo C++ 4.5? Really? That's...pretty old, to put it mildly. Much more modern tools are freely available.